# User-defined commands, like gdb's define, for multiple commands in gnuplot terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

Just thought I'd document this (self-answer to follow):

When working with `gnuplot` in terminal, one can use up and down arrows on keyboard to iterate through the typed commands history - just like in `gdb`.

However, sometimes there may be a sequence of commands I repeat often - which I'd like to call by issuing a single command. For instance, one works with interactive `x11` terminal in `gnuplot`, and wants to obtain a "screenshot" in `png` format. That requires the terminal to be changed to `png`, output to be set, `plot` to be issued, and terminal reverted back to `x11`; or:

```
set terminal png
set output 'gnuplot.png'
replot
set terminal x11
```

I'd like this sequence to be called with a single command - even though I'm aware that these could fit on a single line, by using semicolon as separator:

```
set terminal png ; set output 'gnuplot.png' ; replot ; set terminal x11
```

In `gdb`, there is a command, [define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262639/multiple-commands-in-gdb-separted-by-some-sort-of-delimiter/1262789#1262789), which allows for [user-defined commands](http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_146.html); one simply issues in the `gdb` terminal:

```
(gdb) define fn
> finish
> next
> end
```

... and from that point on, one can type `fn` in that terminal to call the sequence of `finish` and `end`.

Is there something similar to that in `gnuplot`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there seems to be - there is a facility called macros (`help macros` in `gnuplot`), where a string variable can be expanded by prepending the `@` ("at" character) to its name.

This facility is disabled by default, so one needs to think about enabling it. Which is why its best to save that sequence in an init script file, named for instance `init.gp`:

```
print ""
print "init.gp starting"

set terminal x11

# define capt string variable as sequence
# of commands, semicolon separated

capt = "print 'Saving...' ; set terminal png ; set output 'gnuplot.png' ; replot ; set terminal x11"

print "macros state: "
show macros

print "enabling macros state:"
set macros
show macros

print "The @capt command should be available now."
print ""
print "init.gp ending"
print ""
```

Then one can do a terminal session like this in `gnuplot`:

```
$ gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    [...]

Terminal type set to 'wxt'

gnuplot> load "init.gp"

init.gp starting
macros state: 

    command line macros will not be expanded

enabling macros state:

    command line macros will be expanded

The @capt command should be available now.

init.gp ending

gnuplot> plot sin(x)

gnuplot> @capt
Saving...
Terminal type set to 'png'
Options are 'nocrop font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf 12 size 640,480 '
Terminal type set to 'x11'
Options are ' nopersist'

gnuplot> plot cos(x)
Closing gnuplot.png

gnuplot> exit

$ identify gnuplot.png 
gnuplot.png PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 102c 5.58KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: As a side note, gnuplot looks in the user's home directory for `.gnuplot` (on *NIX -- Not sure what the file is on windows) when you start working in interactive mode.  That script would then be loaded automatically.  There's also the environment variable `GNUPLOT_LIB` which is a directory that `load` will search for the requested file.