# Run multiple commands in gdb

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to run multiple commands in `gdb` such as the following:

```
# step instruction and then print what I want to see again
>>> si && x/bt $rsi
```

If so, how can it be done?

Comment: How about a [user-defined command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html), would that work for you?

Comment: @ssbssa nah, I have a few of those, I just find myself often doing an `s`, `si` and then wanting to print a value right after that instruction.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have multiple commands in one line.
I guess the [Automatic Display](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html) is also not what you want.
The [Ctrl-o binding](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Syntax.html) may or may not help you a bit thou.

Comment: @ssbssa thanks for the tip regarding Automatic Display, that works nicely for this: `display/bt $rsi`.

Comment: @ssbssa what's the difference between pressing `[enter]` and `ctrl-o` ?

Comment: In your case, if you did `si` and `x/bt $rsi` before, and they are now in your command history, you can go back in the history to `si` and press ctrl-o. This executes the command, just like [enter], but then automatically goes to the `x/bt $rsi` command.

Comment: @ssbssa want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262639/72178.

Comment: [User-defined commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html) as mentioned by @ssbssa are the way to go, but for something quick and dirty [keyboard macros](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Keyboard-Macros.html) are also a good option.

Answer (score 2):

If your gdb includes python, follow this post to add a user command in your .gdbinit file:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51804606/11873710

Usage example:

```
(gdb) cmds echo hi ; echo bye
hi
bye
```